# Какое у меня "так", если не наречие, союз, частица, вводное слово? Каких знаков требует?

Tags: пунктуация

[**ТАК**, наречие, союз, частица, вводное слово](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_707)

Речь об огромной семье, обитающей на огромной же территории.

> У семьи свои земли – виноградники, винодельня, фрукты, овощи, скот.
>   Сёстры **так** предпочитают передвигаться верхом.

Чую, что вместо **так** могло быть **те**... Какой знак нужен перед уточняющим словцом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Возможные варианты:**

**Сёстры, так те** предпочитают передвигаться верхом.

**Сестры ―  так те вообще** предпочитают передвигаться верхом.

Это сокращенный вариант предложения: Что касается сестер, то они вообще предпочитают не ходить, а передвигаться верхом.

Примеры

**Сестры ― те,** вообще не знаю, спят ли? [Николай Амосов. Голоса времен (1999)]

Ребята, **так те вообще** готовы наглеца «Магнумом» этим накормить. [Алексей Лукьянов. Артиллеристы. Занимательные истории о богах войны // «Октябрь», 2003]

А работяги ― **так те вообще** по сто. [Виктор Левашов. Заговор патриота (2000)]

Ну, а рабочие и крестьянство, **так те воюют**. [Н. А. Островский. Рожденные бурей (1934-1936)]

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, здесь частица, означающая подчёркивание. Словарь Кузнецова говорит:

> 3. Употр. для подчёркивания, выделения при противопоставлении, сопоставлении. ... **Вот он так настоящий учёный!**

Не требует знаков препинания.

Comment: Нет, не мой случай. А что было бы, если:  *Сёстры(?) те предпочитают передвигаться верхом.*

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova А я считаю, что Ваш. Если бы так, тогда было бы тире. Как и в моём варианте: *Вот Иванов -- тот настоящий учёный!*